# Html no me reconoce la etiqueta php en vs code

Tags: php, html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
         echo "Hola mundo";
      ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Visual studio code no me reconoce la etiqueta php dentro del html. En configuración ya tengo agregado el path del ejecutable php y con hojas externas no hay problema pero al usarlo dentro del body, me marca la etiqueta de apertura php en rojo.

[image: Etiqueta php en rojo]

Comment: abajo a la derecha "language mode" elige php, no hace falta interprete ( ejecutable ) si el basic php integrado no ayuda instala una extensión tipo [Intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense)

Comment: Correcto, este detalle era. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, deberías asegurarte para empezar que estés en un archivo con la extensión php, este es prácticamente un archivo .html con el agregado de que puedes utilizar PHP dentro para programar.

Answer (score 1):

si ya pusiste la dirección de tu ejecutable php en el path algo asi

```
    "php.validate.enable": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"php.validate.run": "onSave",
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
"intelephense.phpdoc.propertyTemplate": {
```

asi deberia quedar (depende de tu php donde se encuentre) ,igual instala una extension de php yo uso la de PHP Intelephense creo que eso es lo que te faltaria (cuando escribo igual se me pone asi y luego se edita en azul imagino que es por la extension)

con ctrl + , abres la configuracion y en ese buscador escribes php, te aparecen las opciones de php, debes habilitarlas si en dado caso no estan(ahi igual esta el editar del json para que cheques lo que puse arriba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

anexe unas imagenes de donde debes cambiar el tipo de lenguaje

Comment: Nada. Tengo todo igual, incluso la extensión y no la detecta. En hojas externas .php no hay problema, las reconoce perfectamente. Es dentro del html que no la coge.

Comment: en la barra de abajo, aparece el tipo de lenguaje que estas usando por defecto te pone el que tienes, pero creo que por extensiones cuando ve php lo cambia, checa si poniendolo en php te sirve, anexo imagen en la respuesta

Comment: Para que HTML reconozca código PHP tiene que estar en un archivo PHP valga la redundancia, ejemplo **index.php** y dentro de este archivo genera el HTML.